# Codepush deployment to staging triggers production app update request

Tags: react-native, code-push

I've integrated CodePush into my react-native app and set up the Staging and Production environments. I've set it up so I can run the app locally in debug and have that use the staging config and also run the app in release mode and have that use the release config (https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-android.md).

After releasing to staging (not promoted to production at this point), when I run the app locally in release mode it prompts to update. This shouldn't happen as it should only happen on the promotion of that release to prod?

Comment: This should not happen. Have you assigned different keys to each of your schemes [iOS](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-ios.md) | [Android](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-android.md)? My only guess is that both of your builds are using the same Code Push deployment key.

Comment: Also, anyone reading this should be aware that CodePush is [now being rolled into Visual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) and support will stop September 2018.